# Deduping results returned by a Mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

### Some background:

This involves 3 collections:

1. posts
2. postsubcategories
3. postsupercategories

Example of a document in posts:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57fbf3ce7ccbc906ed87cef6"),
    "__v" : 6,
    "author" : ObjectId("57fbe2ac3cfb9e061df86ebb"),
    "postSubCategories" : [ 
        ObjectId("5806344baa0bbf284a2316e4")//reference to document in postsubcategories collection
    ],
    "postSuperCategories" : [ 
        ObjectId("580679958a5f5f448ba5aae9"), 
        ObjectId("580679958a5f5f448ba5aaf2")//references to documents in postsupercategories collection
    ],
    "publishedDate" : ISODate("2016-10-10T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "state" : "published",
    "templateName" : ObjectId("57fbf3977ccbc906ed87cef3"),
    "title" : "My title",
    "topics" : []}
```

My query is

```
db.posts.aggregate([
{'$unwind': 
    {'path':"$postSubCategories"}
},
{'$lookup': {
  'from':"postsubcategories",
  'localField': "postSubCategories",
  'foreignField': "_id",
  'as': "subObject"
}},
{'$unwind': 
    {'path':"$postSuperCategories"}
},
{'$lookup': {
  'from':"postsupercategories",
  'localField': "postSuperCategories",
  'foreignField': "_id",
  'as': "superObject"
}},
{'$match': {
    '$or':
        [{ "subObject.searchKeywords": "home monitor" }, 
        { "superObject.searchKeywords": "home monitor" }]
    }
},
{'$match': {
    "state": "published"
}}
```

Both postsubcategories and postsupercategories collections contain a field called searchKeywords that is an array of text within their documents. I want to be able to query those searchKeywords fields and return the posts documents that match. I need a deduped set of returned _ids.

The query is returning four documents. Example:

```
ObjectId("57fbf3ce7ccbc906ed87cef6")
ObjectId("57fbf3ce7ccbc906ed87cef6")
ObjectId("57fbf40b7ccbc906ed87cef7")
ObjectId("57fbf40b7ccbc906ed87cef7")
```

I understand why it is returning 4. One document contains postSubCategories object `5806344baa0bbf284a2316e4` and postSuperCategories id `580679958a5f5f448ba5aae9`. 
The second document contains postSubCategories object `5806344baa0bbf284a2316e4` and postSuperCategories `580679958a5f5f448ba5aaf2`. This repeats for the second post

### Is there a way that I can "dedupe" based on the _ids that are returned?

My end result would be:

```
ObjectId("57fbf3ce7ccbc906ed87cef6")
ObjectId("57fbf40b7ccbc906ed87cef7")
```

I know that technically the 2 matching _ids from the list of 4 are not the exact same because they each contain a different postSuperCategories object, but at this point I don't care about that field anymore and just need a singular posts document because I need access to the other fields. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried looking into `$group`, `$addToSet`, and `$setUnion` and have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one `$group` retrieving distinct `_id` with the first value found for each of the properties you want to extract per `_id`.

for the `$group` aggregation :

```
{
    '$group': {
        _id: '$_id',
        item: { $first: "$$ROOT" } 
    }
}
```

which will give you the first item for [root document](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) in `item` field :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57fbf40b7ccbc906ed87cef7"), "items" : { "_id" : ObjectId("57fbf40b7ccbc906ed87cef7"), "__v" : 6, "author" : ObjectId("57fbe2ac3cfb9e061df86ebb"), "postSubCategories" : ObjectId("5806344baa0bbf284a2316e4"), "postSuperCategories" : ObjectId("580679958a5f5f448ba5aae9"), "publishedDate" : ISODate("2016-12-10T04:00:00Z"), "state" : "published", "templateName" : ObjectId("57fbf3977ccbc906ed87cef4"), "title" : "My title2", "topics" : [ "a", "b" ], "subObject" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5806344baa0bbf284a2316e4"), "searchKeywords" : "home monitor" } ], "superObject" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("580679958a5f5f448ba5aae9"), "searchKeywords" : "home monitor2" } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57fbf3ce7ccbc906ed87cef6"), "items" : { "_id" : ObjectId("57fbf3ce7ccbc906ed87cef6"), "__v" : 6, "author" : ObjectId("57fbe2ac3cfb9e061df86ebb"), "postSubCategories" : ObjectId("5806344baa0bbf284a2316e4"), "postSuperCategories" : ObjectId("580679958a5f5f448ba5aae9"), "publishedDate" : ISODate("2016-10-10T04:00:00Z"), "state" : "published", "templateName" : ObjectId("57fbf3977ccbc906ed87cef3"), "title" : "My title", "topics" : [ ], "subObject" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5806344baa0bbf284a2316e4"), "searchKeywords" : "home monitor" } ], "superObject" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("580679958a5f5f448ba5aae9"), "searchKeywords" : "home monitor2" } ] } }
```

Otherwise, for selecting a field in the response :

```
{
    '$group': {
        _id: '$_id',
        author: {
            $first: '$author'
        },
        publishedDate: {
            $first: '$publishedDate'
        },
        state: {
            $first: '$state'
        },
        templateName: {
            $first: '$templateName'
        },
        title: {
            $first: '$title'
        },
        topics: {
            $first: '$topics'
        }
    }
}
```

You will get something like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57fbf40b7ccbc906ed87cef7"), "author" : ObjectId("57fbe2ac3cfb9e061df86ebb"), "publishedDate" : ISODate("2016-10-10T04:00:00Z"), "state" : "published", "templateName" : ObjectId("57fbf3977ccbc906ed87cef3"), "title" : "My title", "topics" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57fbf3ce7ccbc906ed87cef6"), "author" : ObjectId("57fbe2ac3cfb9e061df86ebb"), "publishedDate" : ISODate("2016-10-10T04:00:00Z"), "state" : "published", "templateName" : ObjectId("57fbf3977ccbc906ed87cef3"), "title" : "My title", "topics" : [ ] }
```

Comment: Thanks! I started down this path, but couldn't quite get it. My big concern with doing it this way is it doesn't leave me much flexibility down the road if new fields are added that I want returned. I would have to come into the code and keep updating this query instead of all fields, including any potential new ones being returned automatically.

Comment: I have edited my post with the use of `$first: "$$ROOT" ` to fetch the previous document

Comment: Ah! Just discovered this. This looks to be the best option. Thanks for the help